# How to keep sessions when moving from one application server to another

Tags: multiple-instances, deployment

Assuming I follow the steps in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/149905/production-deployment-to-ec2-with-minimal-downtime/157678#157678) to deploy a new version of an application without downtimes. When I route the users to the new application server instance, the application will not remember their session so they will be logged out without warning.

Is there a way to keep the sessions alive over multiple servers or to make a "session snapshot" or similar?

In my case it's a Java application if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the session data on a separate server that both application servers have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Store the session in Memcache, and allow both servers to have access to the memcache backend.

You could store them on a shared disk, but that's slow and inefficient.  Memcache is pretty much the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into clustering support for your server.  Properly configured clustering will replicate your session data between the two servers.